# {beamer} how to delay footnote to apear along with item?

Tags: beamer, footnotes

In my beamer presentation I want to use footnotes.

Currently the footnotes appear imediately at the frame start although the item having the footnote is not yet visible.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Test Footnote} 
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<+-> statement 1
            \item<+-> statement 2
            \item<+-> statement 3\footnote{this should appear along with statement3}
            \item<+-> statement 4
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How can I have the footnote apearing at the same time as the item it belongs to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should assign overlay specifications to footnotes too

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Test Footnote} 
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<+-> statement 1
            \item<+-> statement 2
            \item<+-> statement 3\footnote<3->{this should appear along with statement3}
            \item<+-> statement 4
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sometimes the solution is closer then you think... ;o) Thanks!

Comment: with `<.->` instead of `<+->` the footnote really appears together with the item

Comment: @TimothyTruckle you're right! I suppose you mean `<.->` instead of `<3->`!

Comment: yes, `<.->` prevents us from counting the items and changing the number when the footnoted item moves up or down...